# iOS Swift: Array of Range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, range

I have a `Player` class that stores a `rating` property of type `Int`:

```
class Player {
    typealias Rating: Int
    var rating: Rating = 0
}
```

I then have various `Range` instances that specify the `level` that a given `player` is at:

```
private let level1Range = 0 ..< 100
private let level2Range = 100 ..< 500
```

I can then `switch` on the `player` `rating` property to obtain the level that the `player` is at:

```
switch rating {
case level1Range:
    print("On Level 1")
case level2Range:
    print("On Level 2")
default:
    break
}
```

**I want to be able to say what the next level is and how far away the `player` is from that next level.**

I'm not sure of the best way to go out this problem. I started by making an array:

```
private var ratingRanges: [Range] {
    return [level1Range, level2Range]
}
```

But I get the error:

*Reference to generic type 'Range' requires arguments in <...>
Insert '<<#Bound: Comparable#>>'*

If this worked, I guess I could then find the first non-zero value:

```
ratingRanges.first(where: { $0.min() - self.rating > 0 })
```

in order to locate the next range.

**Or is there a more efficient method to achieve this?**

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the generic placeholder type of the `Range`:

```
private var ratingRanges: [Range<Rating>] {
    return [level1Range, level2Range]
}
```

Or simpler, with automatic type inference, as a (lazy) stored property:

```
private lazy var ratingRanges = [level1Range, level2Range]
```

Determining the next range can then be done as

```
func nextRange() -> Range<Rating>? {
    return ratingRanges.first(where: { $0.lowerBound > rating})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to create **Level** enum:

```
    enum Level: Int {
    case level1 = 1
    case level2

    init?(rating: Int) {
        switch rating {
        case Level.level1.range:
            self = .level1
        case Level.level2.range:
            self = .level2
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    var range: CountableRange<Int> {
        switch self {
        case .level1:
            return level1Range
        case .level2:
            return level2Range
        }
    }
}
```

And then all you need to do is to add following methods to your **Player** class:

```
func nextLevel() -> Level? {
    guard let currentLevel = Level(rating: rating) else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let nextLevel = Level(rawValue: currentLevel.rawValue + 1) else {
        return nil
    }
    return nextLevel
}

func distanceTo(level: Level) -> Int {
    let levelLowerBound = level.range.lowerBound
    return levelLowerBound - rating
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, it does look a little more involved than the accepted answer though.

Answer (score 0):

May you should to keep the maximum value of range only. For example, instead of

```
private let level1Range = 0 ..< 100
private let level2Range = 100 ..< 500
```

you can use

```
private let level1MaxRating = 100
private let level2MaxRating = 500
```

and compare with

```
switch rating {
case 0...level1MaxRating:
    print("level 1")
case (level1MaxRating+1)...level2MaxRating:
    print("level 2")
}
```